# How to copy all properties from one JavaBean to Another with different attribute name?

Tags: java, javabeans

I want to copy properties of a large number of beans from one JavaBean to another. I looked at Apache Commons [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html). But the problem is that it expects the Attribute names to be the same in both beans. There is no way to provide a mapping.

E.g. In my bean 1 the attribute maybe *firstName* while in bean 2 it may be *name*.

Hence I want some way to transparently copy these properties and if possible provide a mapping somewhere between attribute names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). It supports the mapping you are expecting. They support mapping via XML, annotations etc.

Check [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html) for simple example.